# `No manual entry for nfs.5` Does this means my installed man pages are incomplete? Or something else?

Tags: man

```
$ man nfs.5
No manual entry for nfs.5
```

Does above means my installed man pages are incomplete? Or something else? How to install complete? System is Linux Mint 20.2 (also checked on Ubuntu 20.4 - same).

*TL;DR*

I wanted to set a network share / mount. I did:

```
$ man -k nfs
confstr (3)          - get configuration dependent string variables
filesystems (5)      - Linux filesystem types: ext, ext2, ext3, ext4, hpfs, iso9660, JFS, minix, msdos, ncpfs nfs, ntfs, proc, Reiserfs, smb, sysv, umsdos,...
fs (5)               - Linux filesystem types: ext, ext2, ext3, ext4, hpfs, iso9660, JFS, minix, msdos, ncpfs nfs, ntfs, proc, Reiserfs, smb, sysv, umsdos,...
nfsservctl (2)       - syscall interface to kernel nfs daemon
```

Then:

```
$ man fs
```

> SEE ALSO
> fuse(4), btrfs(5), ext2(5), ext3(5), ext4(5), nfs(5), proc(5), tmpfs(5), fsck(8), mkfs(8), mount(8)

```
$ man nfs.5
No manual entry for nfs.5

$ man nfsservctl
```

> Note: Since Linux 3.1, this system call no longer exists.  It has been
> replaced by a set of files in the nfsd filesystem; see nfsd(7).

```
$ man nfsd.7
No manual entry for nfsd.7
```

Comment: `nfs.5` is the filename containing the `nroff` source of the `man` page. `msn 7 nfsd`  (read `man man`) is the way to go.

Comment: @waltinator On a modern `man` command, `man nfs.5` is simply an alternate way to say `man 5 nfs`. You can also ask `man` to display a man page that is not installed yet, by specifying something that explicitly looks like a pathname, e.g. `man ./nfs.5` if you have just extracted the latest and greatesta `nfs-utils` source code package and trying to see if the man page patch you submitted was applied or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Debian, the `nfs(5)` man page is part of the `nfs-common` package, and I would expect the same to be true in Debian-derivatives like Ubuntu and Mint.

If you don't have any NFS-related packages installed, you might not have `nfs-common` installed either, as `nfs-common` now replaces the old `nfs-client` package, and both user-space and kernel-space NFS server packages (`nfs-ganesha` and `nfs-kernel-server`, respectively) depend on `nfs-common`.